# Difference in heart muscle tissue growth (cardio vs low-rep intense weight lifting)

Tags: cardiology, heart, heart-rate, heartbeat

Below is a quote from a [subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fitness/comments/58hufp/weightlifting_and_heart_muscle/) that says:

> I haven't kept up on the research, but the last thing I read back in college looked at weight lifters and long distance runners. Both types had larger than normal hearts. The chambers of the weight lifters hearts had thick, walls, and were smaller. The runners had huge chambers but thinner walls. I do both, and my heart is larger than normal, but I've no idea what the internal structure looks like.

Other comments resemble the one above. Is that correct? Does that mean that cardio is better for lowering your heart-rate(e.g. from 70-80 to 50-60)? Also if the heart thickens the tissue and reduces the space in the chambers, doesn't that force it to beat faster?

P.S. this could be more appropriate for the fitness stack exchange but I wasn't sure where I'd get more accurate responses.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to achieve a certain result, and that makes it squarely off topic here. It's possibly on topic on Fitness under the heading of "choosing a fitness program" but I think they'll expect you to say what you're trying to achieve. On the other hand, if this is purely an academic question it's fine here.

Comment: I see you put a subreddit quote on here and as this is a scientific site, we do require evidence of some prior research which the subreddit quote fulfills in a sense. I wonder though if you did some searches for medical science related articles on the way exercise affects the heart. If so, could you please [edit] your question to give some details? @CareyGregory - I agree that this could potentially be off-topic but I am inclined to treat this as an academic question as it is looking at physical changes with the heart through exercise and it is written in a general academic tone.